# How to fetch all records from both the table based on project-id in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

people_table

```
 id project_id comp_id  people_name
    1   13         1        john
    2   16         2        rob
    3   18         1        jack
    4   18         2        lee
```

company_table

```
 id project_id comp_name
    1   21         axn
    2   13         ibm 
    3   15         anz
```

Comment: if you can so me the result like how

Answer (score 1):

***you need this:***

```
SELECT A.*,B.* 
FROM people_table as A 
INNER JOIN company_table as B 
ON A.project_id = B.project_id
```

***you should check the sqlfiddle:***

***http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ecd2/1***

Answer (score 0):

Try with INNER JOIN

```
SELECT P.*,C.* 
FROM people_table P 
INNER JOIN company_table C ON P.project_id = C.project_id
WHERE P.project_id = $your_project_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
select * from people_table p,company_table c where p.projectID=c.projectID
```

This displays project_ID column twice. So you can use distinct keyword to get one project id column.